# CDN does not work from master page and related pages with content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, cdn

Had to upload sources to our local server.
But our pages without masterpage work with CDN without any problems.
So it does not look like firewall but rather asp server issue.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title />
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>jquery-ui.min.js 
        -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "//" from the source

```
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and put it as

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```